# How can I get rosmake to print warnings

Tags: rosmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello!

Is there a way to print the warnings from rosmake?  I can't seem to find an option to do it.

Thanks!
robert

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10727/how-can-i-get-rosmake-to-print-warnings./) by [Robert](https://answers.ros.org/users/894/robert/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2011-07-25

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

rosmake -V will display all console outputs.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-07-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3